# How to programatically add or delete names in a module

Tags: python

Suppose I create a module on the fly:

```
import imp
my_module = imp.new_module('my_module')
```

and I want to add `n` similar names/value to this module, something that would be equivalent to

```
my_module.a1 = None
my_module.a2 = None
my_module.a3 = None
...
```

How can I access a module namespace like a dictionary (or in a similar way) so that I can write something like

```
for i in range(n):
    my_module.some_env_like_dict[f"a{i}"] = None
```

Also how can I remove these names in a similar way?

I understand that Python may not have a recommended or official way of doing this. Obviously this is not for any serious project.

I'm looking for a solution that is more elegant than using `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing is essentially correct, with just a few additions:

```
my_module = imp.new_module('my_module')
my_module.var1 = 123
```

This creates a module, and sets `var1` to `123` within the module.  You can access it as `my_module.var1` just as you would for any other module.

To access the attributes from strings, you can do:

```
val = getattr(my_module, "var1")
setattr(my_module, "var1", val + 1)
```

This sets `val` to `123`, then updates `var1` in `my_module` with the value `124`.  You can also add new attributes to the module in this manner.